# can we provide access to user access from any IP ranges through permission set

Tags: apex, community, profile, permissions, login

Hi friends I stuck in a place called.

I have a profile with 10 members are assigned.And we set up some Login IP ranges for this profile.

My requirement is i have to give access for one user in the above group can access sfdc from any network.

So,is this possible through permission sets.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, With Permission Sets we can't set the IP Ranges.

In this case, you need to create a new profile exactly same as the existing profile and have a different IP Ranges.

Thanks, 
Pavan